# SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Maybe you meant '==' or ':=' instead of '='? : python shorthand if-else

Tags: python, syntax-error, conditional-operator

```
resources = {
    "water": 300,
    "milk": 200,
    "coffee": 100,
}

prompt = input("What would you like? (espresso, latte or cappuccino):")
if prompt == 'report':
    for i in resources:
        k = 'g' if i == 'coffee' else k = 'ml'
        print(f'{i} : {resources[i]}')
```

Abovementioned code gives me error

```
"k = 'g' if i == 'coffee' else k = 'ml'
    ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Maybe you meant '==' or ':=' instead of '='?"
```

but works when I used print statements instead of assignment statement
like

`print('g') if i == 'coffee' else print('ml')`

Comment: If you want to *do* something on a condition, use an `if` statement, not a ternary expression. `if i == 'coffee': k = 'g'`, `else: k = 'ml'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want:

```
k = 'g' if i == 'coffee' else 'ml'
```

That is to say, there's only one *statement* (the overall `k = ...`); everything on the right of `=` is an *expression* that evaluates to either `'g'` or `'ml'`, so the `k =` can't and shouldn't be repeated.

`print('ml')` is also an expression (albeit one that evaluates to `None`), so it works in that position; but `k = 'ml'` is only a statement and cannot be used in an expression-only context.